# Присвоение приложению права MODIFY_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, permissions

Всем привет!
Есть необходимость выполнить действие для которого нужно системное разрешение MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.
в манифесте оно прописано.
но на попытку выполнить это действие, андроид упрямо отвечает, что такого права у приложения нет!!
что не так делаю? в эмуляторе работает, а на реальном устройстве - нет :(

**UPDATE** ***в связи с описанными ниже в комментарии обстоятельствами*** :(

Конкретизирую вопрос. Задача такова - удалить из панели уведомлений уведомление о пропущенных вызовах. сами вызовы из списка вызовов убиваются программно. т.е. если войти в список вызовов системы, то уведомление из панели исчезает автоматом, т.к. вызовов уже и нет. Т.е. автоматом выполняется синхронизации одного с другим. Как бы извратиться так, чтобы после программного удаления вызовов из системы заставить панель уведомлений прочухаться и самой осознать, что уведомление о пропущенных надо бы убрать, ибо пропущенных как бы и нет уже?

Comment: Какая версия на реальном устройстве ?

Comment: 2.3.3. на другом 2.3.6. везде одно и то же -ругается на отсутствие прав на управление системой.хотя они в манифесте прописаны.
зато вчера испробовал на планшете.ноунейм китайский с, наверное, китайским же андроидом 4.1.там всё работает.видимо рут-права не убиваются у приложения по умолчанию при установке.
вычитал под вечер, что андроидо-пейсатели, делающие типа официальные версии андроида,спецом закрыли назначение системных прав для сторонних приложений начиная где-то как раз с версии 2.3. типа испугались что кто-то начнет вирусы писать для их гадской шняги. и вот теперь честным людям мучатьс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пермишен `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` может получить только приложение подписанное ключом производителя аппарата - ну или по другому системное приложение. Аппы простых смертных не имеют такой возможности

Comment: но на планшете ведь работает!
значит там либо разрешено всем получать это право, либо???....

Comment: Кетай же - этим все сказано ))

Comment: мой китаец свято верит что он телефон .... и по количеству пикселей не могу с ним спорить _)))

Comment: т.е. китайцы клали на всех и свои версии андрода делают как хотят? :)
молодцы, что тут сказать. и здесь впереди планеты всей!

а что касается второй части вопроса - про очистку панели уведомлений от пропущенных вызовов после их удаления - какие-то идеи есть?